# parent component won't show up if I don't pass all the props to the child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

First of all, it's good to mention that I'm a bit new to react world. I am using Mui with react. here is my code:

```
const Search = (props) => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const isSmall = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
    return !isSmall || props.show ? <SearchDiv {...props} /> : null;
};
```

as you can see it's a simple component that under a circumstance returns another custom component. my problem is that if I Don't add {...props} to the child component(SearchDiv) the whole component Search won't show up. but if I add everything works fine and I can't understand why? do we always need to pass all props to any child component?

I searched StackOverflow and google but I didn't find something similar to my question.

**Edit** : here is the rest of the code:

```
const SearchDiv = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    position: "relative",
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: "50%",

   [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
   marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
   },
   [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
   marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
   },
  }));

const Navbar = () => {
  const [showSearch, setShowSearch] = useState(false);

  return (
    <AppBar>
     <Toolbar sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between"     }}>
        <Search show={showSearch}>

        <StyledInputBase
        placeholder="Search…"
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
        />
        </Search>
        <SearchIcon onClick={() => setShowSearch(true)} />

      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Show us the base code for SearchDiv  component. We have no idea what it expects or what it renders. See: [mre]

Comment: Where does `styled()` come from?

Comment: it's MUI v5. actually, it has been imported from @mui/material/styles

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are right. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, see [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

Without passing props, ie

```html
<SearchDiv />
```

your styled `<div>` has no children to render. When you pass all the parent props via `{...props}`, that includes `children`, the equivalent of...

```html
<SearchDiv children={props.children} show={props.show} />
```

I wouldn't recommend this though. An alternative would be

```html
<SearchDiv>
  { props.children }
</SearchDiv>
```

as per the [containment](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment) section of the guide linked above.